# WPF image and text alignment in button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I need a way to align a label to right and align an image to right. I tried this code:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Height="51">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="Resources/Accept-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <Label Content="ذخیره" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="2  badr" FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

But I see label sticks to image.

**Also** is there any way to have some parameter like cell padding (from right/left/top/bottom)?

Comment: Try using the `Padding` property for 'cell padding'. You can use it on any `Control`: See the [Control.Padding Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.padding.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using `Grid` instead of `StackPanel`

```
<Grid>
   <Image ... HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
   <Label ... HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

there is `Padding` property which is published by types like [`Block`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.aspx), [`Border`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx), [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.padding.aspx), and [`TextBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) so for example it will not be published by `Image` control, which inherits directly from `FrameworkElement`, but will be by `Label` which is a `Control`

Answer (score 10):

Try using a `DockPanel` instead

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Height="51">
  <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image Source="Resources/Accept-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
    <Label Content="ذخیره" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="2  badr" FontSize="20"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Button>
```

For your padding question, which element are you trying to pad?

Comment: Thank you Richard. Your answer is great for me... There is no need to cell padding. I find it. (+1)

Comment: Result! I've been pulling my hair out trying all sorts of ideas, so annoying when these little things waste hours of valuable time. Thanks for the answer, +1 to @Richard

Comment: Glad to have helped @DIGGIDY